# How do I strip all "\" from an API response in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pulling a massive list of policies from a program using the API in Python.

When I pull them using:

```
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(response.text)
        print("Invalid Response")
        sys.exit(1)
    return response.json()
```

Some of the metadata values are having characters added.

e.g. In the programme, the name of a policy is 'Ensure the "root" account usage...'
But in the response, it's being presented as:

```
"name": 'Ensure the \"root\" account usage...',
```

As you can see, there are two "\" being added.

Now, when I try to use a different API to re-create this policy in the programme, it rejects it because of the "\".

The response is a **list** of **dictionaries**. The dictionaries contains multiple metadata fields e.g. name (as seen), description, recommendation etc. in which this issue is occurring.

**Question**:
How can I cycle through my list of dictionaries in the response, and remove all "\" or is there a better way to do it?

Cheers!

---

Update: API Response example with data removed

```
[
  {
    "policyId": "text",
    "name": "text",
    "policyType": "text",
    "policySubTypes": [
      "text"
    ],
    "systemDefault": boolean,
    "description": "text.",
    "severity": "text",
    "rule": {
      "name": "text",
      "criteria": "text",
      "parameters": {
        "savedSearch": "text"
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "recommendation": "text u00a0 \u00a0 text \u00a0 text"
    "cloudType": "",
    "complianceMetadata": {
      "standardName": "text",
      "standardDescription": "text",
      "requirementId": 1,
      "requirementName": "text",
      "sectionId": "text",
      "sectionDescription": "text",
      "complianceId": "text",
      "policyId": "text/number",
      "systemDefault": "boolean",
      "customAssigned": "boolean"
    },
    "labels": [
      "text"
    ],
    "enabled": boolean,
    "deleted": boolean,
    "remediable": boolean
  },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make the replacement with `newstr = oldstr.replace("\\", "")`.

To cycle through list of dictionaries:

```
for dic in dic_list:
  for k,v in dic.items():
    if isinstance(v, str):
       dic[k] = v.replace("\\", "")
```

Comment: I can't use .replace because the "\" is an escape character? It kicks out errors if I try .replace("\","")

Comment: @RyanBrown If you believe there is actually a literal "\" in the string so `.replace("\\", '')` should work...

Comment: So I tried this, replacing "dic_list" with my list of dictionaries variable, but I got hit with this: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: The data structure might be different to what you described then... the values of your dictionary might be lists, not just strings - Add that loop.

Comment: I've updated the OP with an example of the structure with the data removed. That one dictionary structure is replicated many times in the list. Notice, I also get those u00a0 etc. and other weird characters

Comment: So your dictionaries not only contain string types.. there's also nested dictionaries and lists... You can add a check for the values to be a string - check edit.